# Novel(?) method of generating Motzkin numbers, Catalan partial sums, and other sequences

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, reference-request

For solutions to the equations (1/X)+(1/Y)=K  and (X+Y)=1+(1/k) the answer is a pair of points. The X and Y values of a point represent stable points in a two-cycle orbit of the logistic equation using K as input.

For example, for K=3.14159 the results are .781031... and .53727... which are indeed the two values obtained by plugging 3.14159 into the logistic equation.

For large values of K these solutions often generate sequences embedded into the decimal representation of the points.

For example, for

```
k=10)        .111251780630393896979680584629184521

k=100)      0.1010102040921523031574757410327e-1

k=1000)     0.1001001002004009021051127323837e-2

k=10000)    0.00010001000100020004000900210051
```

as K increases by powers of 10 the number of padding zeros increases but more terms of the sequence are observable. In this case the sequence is:

```
1,1,1,2,4,9,21,51,127,323,835...
```

which is equivalent to Sloane's [A001006](https://oeis.org/A001006), the Motzkin numbers (with an additional leading '1').
 For K= 99999999999999999999999999999999999999999 one of the points results in a sequence of:

```
1,2,4,9,23,65,197,626,2056...
```

which is Sloane's [A014137](https://oeis.org/A014137), partial sums of Catalan numbers. As you might guess, various other large K repdigits and near repdigits create their own sequences.

In short, can anyone point me to references on this or related items?

I've had little luck looking online and I'm not a mathematician so my knowledge of the literature is limited.

P.S. I generate solutions using Maple:

```
 proc (z) -> solve({x+y = 1+1/z, 1/x+1/y = z}, {x, y}) end proc;
```

Answer (score 1):

In short you are finding the [generating functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function) of these sequences in a somewhat indirect way. Write $t = \frac{1}{k}$. We have $x = 1 + t - y$ and substituting this in the first equation gives

$$\frac{1}{1 + t - y} + \frac{1}{y} = \frac{1}{t}.$$

Clearing denominators gives

$$t + t^2 = y + ty - y^2$$

hence $y^2 - (1 + t) y + (t + t^2) = 0$, and solving for $y$ gives

$$y = \frac{1 + t \pm \sqrt{1 - 2t - 3t^2}}{2}.$$

Choosing the negative sign produces the power series

$$y = t + t^2 + t^3 + 2t^4 + 4t^5 + 9t^6 + \dots$$

which is, maybe up to a shift, the generating function of the Motzkin numbers. The fact that the Motzkin numbers, Catalan numbers, etc. have generating functions satisfying quadratic equations reflects their relationship to counting trees; there is a long and interesting story here.